# CentOS Apache + Tomcat SSL using mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, mod-jk

I have Apache + Tomcat (using mod_jk) working correctly on a CentOS 6.3 machine.  I am trying to set up SSL with Apache.  When I browse to the site I get the following output:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Here are the relevant conf files:

**/DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/jk/mod_jk.conf:**
This is linked symbolically to the /etc/httpd/conf.d directory

```
LoadModule              jk_module       /DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/jk/mod_jk-1.2.31-httpd-2.2.x.so
JkWorkersFile           /DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/jk/workers.properties
JkMountFile             /DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/jk/uriworkermap.properties
JkShmFile               /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogFile               /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogStampFormat        "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkMount /* worker1
JkLogLevel              info
# SSL Additions below:
JkExtractSSL            On    
JkHTTPSIndicator        HTTPS
JkSessionIndicator      SSL_SESSION_ID
JkCIPHERIndicator       SSL_CIPHER
JkCERTSIndicator        SSL_CLIENT_CERT
```

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:**
I only added 1 line at the very end of the file when trying to configure SSL.
I included the entire file just in case.

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

PidFile run/httpd.pid


Timeout 60

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15


<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>


<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Listen 80


LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

Include conf.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache


ServerAdmin root@localhost


UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">


    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks


    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>


<IfModule mod_userdir.c>

    UserDir disabled

</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var


AccessFileName .htaccess


<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>


TypesConfig /etc/mime.types


DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog logs/error_log


LogLevel warn

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog logs/access_log combined

ServerSignature On


Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"


<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>



IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8

AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html

IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t


AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW

ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8



AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz


#   MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
AddHandler type-map var

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully


##################################################Added when trying to configure SSL:
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:**

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default



SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin


<VirtualHost _default_:443>


ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn


SSLEngine on


SSLProtocol all -SSLv2


SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key


<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>


SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"



########################### Added here for SSL
Alias / "/DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/"
<Directory "/DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

</Directory>


#JkMount /alesia/servlet/* ajp13
#JkMount /alesia/*.jsp ajp13

JkMount /*.jsp worker1

<Location "/DIR/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/">
AllowOverride None
Deny from all
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I added the end of the file when trying to configure SSL.  I modified the line in the guide I was following to be:

> JkMount /*.jsp worker1

since my mod_jk.conf references worker1, but I'm not sure if this line is required.

When I browse to < server IP >/WEB-INF/  I get a list of the files in the ROOT/WEB-INF so it looks like it's pointing to the correct folder, I just don't have permission to view or execute the files?

I know that the self-signed cert is working since before any re-configuration it was serving the default docroot successfully.

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server), may be it will help you to resolve your issue.